# SsdLife says "drive health is bad" on my CT240M500SSD1

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I bought a new ssd **CT240M500SSD1**, and got win7 installed, then tried SSDLife:
[image]

Does anyone have experienced the same issue? I have only 3 days to have my goods returned %>_<%
SOS~~~~

Here is the SMART info of it, seems all values are invalid :
[image]

ps: does that have something to do with my firmware version **MU05**?

I've also posted the issue here: http://forum.crucial.com/t5/Solid-State-Drives-SSD/ssdLife-says-quot-drive-health-is-bad-quot-on-my-CT240M500SSD1/td-p/156337
Hope someone could help soon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool is outdated and doesn't understand the data from your new SSD. Ignore it and only use newer tools like [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html)